# Windows phone 8 - Event to get media player running status

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to know if there is any way to find out from the code, whether the Windows phone 8 is running media player in the background? and its status like Playing, Pause, Stopped etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference to the instance of the [`BackgroundAudioPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

e.g.

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState
```